# How to rebase a branch and its descendant?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

What I have:

```
master --- A --- B --- b1
       \
        ----- b2 --- C --- b3
```

`A`, `B` and `C` are commits; `b1`, `b2` and `b3` are branches (commits with branches pointing to them).

What I want:

```
master --- A --- B --- b1 --- b2 --- C --- b3
```

Comment: `$ git checkout b3` `$ git rebase b1`?

Comment: And then just reset b2 to its respective commit. Didn't think of that. :)

Comment: Then fast-forward your HEAD, everyone leaves that bit out :)  @LukeHutton, care to make that an answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do it is with two separate rebase commands:

```
git checkout b2
git rebase b1
git checkout b1 #optional
git merge b2 #optional
git checkout b3
git rebase b2
git checkout b2 #optional
git merge b3 #optional
```

and your tree will be like

```
master --- A --- B --- b1 --- b2 --- C --- b3
```

and no `reset` is needed.

Comment: Hm, I tried that and I got a lot of conflicts on `git rebase b2` because it tried to replay all the commits between master and old b2.